# Modal is not closing in my react-native app?

Tags: javascript, react-native, jsx, mobx-react

I am creating a app in which I am using Modal in different screens. I have created a common component for all Modal. I am passing jsx in it and make it visible according to a Global variable. But problem comes when I am opening a modal and then closing it and moving to next screen and then open another modal in next screen , the modal of previous screen is also coming in background.

I tried to make it visible on basis of two variable like on Global variable and another local variable but still modal is not closing.

**This is my common modal component**

```
  render() {
    let { GlobalStore, renderContent = () => {}, modalStyle, modalHeight = '50%' } = this.props;
    return (
      <Modal
        isVisible={GlobalStore.showModal}
        backdropColor={Constants.COLORS.BLACK}
        backdropOpacity={0.4}
        onBackdropPress={() => GlobalStore.toggleModal(false)}
        style={[styles.bottomModal,modalStyle]}>
        <View style={[styles.modalContent,{height: modalHeight}]}>
          {renderContent}
        </View>
      </Modal>
    )
  }
}
```

**and using it on screens like**

```
   {this.openModal?
    <CustomModal visible={GlobalStore.showModal&&this.openModal} 
      modalHeight = {this.modalHeight} renderContent = 
      {this.ModalContent()}/>
       :
     null
    }
```

I just want to close previous modals that are coming in background. I don't want to create different files for all modals.Any kind of help will be appreciated .Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

make GlobalStore.showModal a string rather than a bool.

```
    //action
    const showModal = (modalType = "GLOBAL") => ({type: "SHOW_MODAL", modalType})


    //common modal
    //dispatch action
    dispatch(showModal());
    //check for the visibbility with the global string
    <Modal
        isVisible={GlobalStore.showModal === "GLOBAL"}
        {...restProps}
    />


    //custom modal
    //dispatch action with custom string
    dispatch(showModal("CUSTOM_MODAL"));
    //check for the visibilty with that custom string
    <CustomModal
        isVisible={GlobalStore.showModal === "CUSTOM_MODAL"}
        {...restProps}
    />

    //hide all the modals
    dispatch(showModal(""))
```

Comment: Why? I mean what is the difference in both and what is problem with bool?

Comment: You can check for a matching string instead of bool(this will allow only the matching string to be visible). In the above example, action dispatches string(CUSTOM_MODAL for you custom modal and GLOBAL for you common) instead of bool. And you can check this string in your modal(whichever it is).

Answer (score 0):

Models are overlay special components, however they should be controlled by their parent components. I think you are not unmounting previous screen and because you are using a single global variable, all of unmounted modals have value true. I would either move the visibility variable to state component and limit scope Or you can use the suggestion with a string, but name various modals so the global variable points only to one modal.